# What is the best way to find all dates that match the date you entered?

Tags: sql, oracle, type-conversion

I am trying to get all results from Oracle DB using SQL Developer by corresponding date.

My data:

```
ID         | date_time_of_identification
--------------------------------------------
1240088696 | 22-SEP-19 06.24.23.432000000 AM
1239485087 | 21-SEP-19 09.25.45.912000000 AM
1239228398 | 21-SEP-19 07.18.40.555000000 AM
1239223300 | 21-SEP-19 07.16.39.812000000 AM
1233224199 | 18-SEP-19 10.54.04.023000000 AM
1232432331 | 18-SEP-19 05.06.40.383000000 AM
1231492850 | 17-SEP-19 01.06.05.316000000 PM
```

So I am trying to get all rows from 21.09.2019, then I am writing:

```
select * from mytable where date_time_of_identification = TO_DATE('2019/09/21', 'yyyy/mm/dd'); -- no result
```

Now I am trying to write better query:

```
select * from mytable 
where to_char(date_time_of_identification, 'yyyy/mm/dd') = to_char(TO_DATE('2019/09/21', 'yyyy/mm/dd'), 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

It returns good result, but Is there a better solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You'll have to truncate your date from column to lose the timestamp part:

```
 select * 
   from mytable 
  where trunc(date_time_of_identification) = TO_DATE('2019/09/21', 'yyyy/mm/dd');
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that your predicate is reasonably selective (i.e. the number of rows on a particular day is a small fraction of the number of rows in the table), you'd generally want your query to be able to use an index on `date_time_of_identification`.  If you apply a function to that column, you won't be able to use an index.  So you'd generally want to write this as

```
select *
  from myTable
 where date_time_of_identification >= date '2019-09-21'
   and date_time_of_identification <  date '2019-09-22'
```

The alternative would be to create a function-based index on `date_time_of_identification` and then use that function in the query.

```
create index fbi_myTable
    on trunc( date_time_of_identification );

select *
  from myTable
 where trunc( date_time_of_identification ) = date '2019-09-21';
```